# go back and shared_preferences

Tags: flutter, android-studio

Good morning,
I have several pages, with a button in the appbar that works very well to change the language, when I change the language I close the application and I reopen the application everything works very well.
When I change the language and I navigate between the pages by clicking on the images it works very well too.

My problem is just when I change the language and I click on the left arrow at the top of the flutter app (appbar) the language change is not applied in the previous page! Can you help me please.
THANKS.

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firstapps/language/langue.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:firstapps/pages/auther/Index_history.dart';
import 'package:firstapps/pages/Visites.dart';
import 'package:firstapps/pages/Carte.dart';
import 'package:firstapps/pages/mv.dart';
import 'package:firstapps/pages/lmhb.dart';
import 'package:firstapps/pages/hbd.dart';

class Accueil extends StatefulWidget {
  const Accueil({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Accueil createState() => _Accueil();
}

class _Accueil extends State<Accueil> {
  late SharedPreferences _prefs;
  String _langue = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SharedPreferences.getInstance().then((prefs) {
      setState(() {
        _prefs = prefs;
        _langue = _prefs.getString('langue') ?? 'fr';
      });
    });
  }

  void _changerLangue(String nouvelleLangue) async {
    setState(() {
      _langue = nouvelleLangue;
    });
    await _prefs.setString('langue', nouvelleLangue);
  }

  Widget _buildGridTile(String title, String imageAsset, Widget page) {
    return GridTile(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
        },
      child: ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(imageAsset),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6), BlendMode.darken), // Assombrit l'image avec un opacité de 0.5
              ),
            ),
                      child: Center(
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 24,
                  fontFamily: 'poppinslight',
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>(
      future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final prefs = snapshot.data!;
          final _language = Language();
          final _langue = prefs.getString('langue') ?? 'fr';

          _language.setLanguage(_langue);

          return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: _language,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(_language.transchoixcat()),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: _langue,
                    onChanged: (String? nouvelleLangue) {
                      if (nouvelleLangue != null) {
                        _changerLangue(nouvelleLangue);
                        _language.setLanguage(nouvelleLangue);
                      }
                    },
                    items: <String>['fr', 'ar'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/flag-${value}.png', // chemin de l'image correspondante
                              height: 24,
                              width: 24,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10,),
                            Text(value),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              body: Center(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2, // nombre de colonnes
                  mainAxisSpacing: 16.0, // espacement vertical entre les images
                  crossAxisSpacing: 16.0, // espacement horizontal entre les images
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  children: [
                    _buildGridTile(_language.transhisttoir(), 'assets/images/histoire.jpg', Index_history()),
                    _buildGridTile(_language.transvisit(), 'assets/images/visites.jpg', Visites()),
                    _buildGridTile(_language.transcart(), 'assets/images/carte.jpg', Carte()),
                    _buildGridTile(_language.transvide(), 'assets/images/mv.jpg', mv()),
                    _buildGridTile(_language.transmise(), 'assets/images/lmhb.jpg', lmhb()),
                    _buildGridTile(_language.transapro(), 'assets/images/hbd.jpg', hbd()),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}```


when i change the language it works great my only problem is with the back button which is in the appbar of flutter, when i change the language and i go back the language is not applied but when i click on the images to lavigate the language is well applied.
````

Answer (score 0):

What you want in this case is persisting the locale using state management. Doing this in screen B and the popping to screen A does not mean screen A will sense the changes and change everything, instead screen A will remain the same as it was when you pushed a new screen onto the navigation stack. How state management would help you in this case:

Change something in screen B or screen A, every change you made to the state is then reflected to every other screen where that state is called.

**Edit:** If you wanted to test whether your data is saved correctly you could push a new screen after the screen where you change the locale.

Comment: I think the rollbacks are made from the history, so the language change is not applied when rolling back!

Comment: Yes definitely, this is as expected though. As long as you're not refreshing the state of your locale don't expect to see the changes outside the screen you're working at, at least not in the list of screens that are in pushed into the navigation stack :).